# How to check order of two lists, checking only the strings within the two lists

Tags: python, list, tuples, comparison

I have two lists, one containing battery cell name with its voltage and another list containing battery cell name with its size. How can I check that the cell names within both lists appear in the same order in the two lists?

```
list1 = [('BATN_CELL_09', 3.184), ('BATN_CELL_04', 3.186), ('BATN_CELL_05', 3.247)]

list2 = [('BATN_CELL_09', 0), ('BATN_CELL_04', 20), ('BATN_CELL_05', 200)]
```

If I just compare one list to the other it returns false due to the values being different. Can I remove the numerical values and create two new list just containing the strings and comparing those? Will the order of the battery cell names stay in the current order?

Comment: `all([l1[0]==l2[0] for l1, l2 in zip(list1, list2)])`

Comment: `all(l1 == l2 for (l1, _), (l2, _) in zip(list1, list2))`

Answer (score 1):

```
all(tupl[0] == list2[index][0] for index, tupl in enumerate(list1))
```

Comment: I changed my answer, since it is more efficient, but your comment makes no sense @TomMcLean, because the isequal operator for two lists considers the order for all items as well.

Comment: @chantax Sorry you're right, deleted my comment

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
list1 = [('BATN_CELL_09', 3.184), ('BATN_CELL_04', 3.186), ('BATN_CELL_05', 3.247)]

list2 = [('BATN_CELL_09', 0), ('BATN_CELL_04', 20), ('BATN_CELL_05', 200)]

for i in range (len(list1)):
    if list1[i][0] == list2[i][0]:
        next
    else:
        print("Error at", list1[i][0], "and", list2[i][0])
```

Comment: Thats what the question states? "How can I check that the cell names within both lists appear in the same order of both lists"

Comment: Yeah that's right @not_speshal, and if it is not in the same order it returns the 'error'

Answer (score -1):

This is my first time answering a question and I have written a function that will check if the names in each list are in the same order:

```
list1 = [('BATN_CELL_09', 3.184), ('BATN_CELL_04', 3.186), ('BATN_CELL_05', 3.247)]
list2 = [('BATN_CELL_09', 0), ('BATN_CELL_04', 20), ('BATN_CELL_05', 200)]


def check(list1, list2):
    list1_names = [elm[0] for elm in list1]
    list2_names = [elm[0] for elm in list2]
    if list1_names == list2_names:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I take the first element of each tuple in list1 and list2 to get a list of battery names, hope this helps!